# What does 1> mean in Visual Studio output window?

Tags: visual-studio

Every line of my output window in Visual Studio 2005 is prepended with the characters "1>"

I don't know what happened but it didn't used to do this.

I have tried searching Google but searching for the string "1>" is problematic even if you search +1> (since the + is supposed to mean exact search).

So, what does this mean?... how do I get rid of it?

Thanks,
~Eric

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Visual Studio supports parallel builds, using more than one CPU core to build a solution.  The 1> prefix indicates the build number that produced the output.  You only really get parallel builds when you have projects that are independent of each other.

Comment: Ahh.. that was it.
I added another processor to my VM.
I didn't think I changed anything in Visual Studio.

Comment: What does the number of CPU has to do with this "1>" prefix? From this answer what I understood is that this indicates the "build number"