# Meaning of the Visual Studio output 1> prompts?

Tags: visual-studio, build, output

When building a project in Visual studio, the output window/tab provides a record of the build with the lines prefixed by a prompt such as 1>, or 25>.

What is the significance of the prompt numbers?

(no amount of googling with the rather generic terms such as "visual studio build output windows prompt" appears to get close ;-)

Comment: Visual Studio supports parallel builds.  The `n>` helps you unravel output when output of concurrent builds get intermingled in the Output window.

Comment: Part of the answer regarding parallel cores doesn't seem to fit, in the sense that my little netbook (Intel Atom) doesn't have the number of cores that I get listed in the output.  Could it be that the numbers relate to the projects being built (which seems to be the case - thanks), and the parallel builds option is a speed up detail?

Comment: Well, sure, `25>` does not mean you have 25 cores.  It means you have 25 projects.

Comment: Thanks, an earlier comment (which I think got edited) confused me regarding the distinction between the core by core parallel builds, and the concurrent builds of multiple projects within a single 'solution' (.sln) - It's the latter that is the `n>` display. (It's not something one dwells on normally - just fix the first fault and retry;-). If you want to put it as a full answer I can accept it, if you'd like the points...

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5501204/what-does-1-mean-in-visual-studio-output-window